# Why is COMException can not be set with both HResult and InnerException

Tags: c#, comexception

[COMException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception(v=vs.110).aspx) exposes constructors for either setting HResult or InnerException.

**Why** is it designed like this ? 
How can i set both of these fields ?

Is creating a derived class and setting HResult from inside it only option ?

HResult has protected set methods.

Comment: The designers were very concerned about HResult.  It matters a lot, every built-in .NET exception has a distinct value for it.  Especially important in the early days.  At least 4.5 made the getter public, matters a lot to WinRT interop.  Sure, derive your own class to get to it.